# A list of all possible full binary trees with n nodes

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree, combinations

This is the link to the problem: [All Possible Full Binary Trees](https://leetcode.com/problems/all-possible-full-binary-trees/solution/).

> Given an integer `n`, return *a list of all possible full binary trees* with `n` nodes. Each node of each tree in the answer must have `Node.val == 0`.
>
> Each element of the answer is the root node of one possible tree. You may return the final list of trees in any order.
>
> A full binary tree is a binary tree where each node has exactly `0` or `2` children.
>
> Example 1:
>
> [image: fivetrees]
>
> Input: `n = 7`
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> [[0,0,0,null,null,0,0,null,null,0,0],
>  [0,0,0,null,null,0,0,0,0],
>  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
>  [0,0,0,0,0,null,null,null,null,0,0],
>  [0,0,0,0,0,null,null,0,0]]
> ```

In this question I have to return a list of all possible Full binary trees, here is my java code to the solution, can anyone help me in getting where my code is getting wrong, for every input my code is giving the empty list.

```java
class Solution {
    public List<TreeNode> allPossibleFBT(int n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            List<TreeNode> list = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
            list.add(new TreeNode(0));
            return list;
        }
        List<TreeNode> left;
        List<TreeNode> right;
        List<TreeNode> all = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i + 2) {
            left = allPossibleFBT(i);
            right = allPossibleFBT(n - i - 1);

            for (int k = 0; i < left.size(); k++) {
                for (TreeNode treeNode : right) {
                    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(0);
                    root.left = left.get(k);
                    root.right = treeNode;
                    all.add(root);
                }
            }
        }
        return all;
    }
}
```

TreeNode Class:

```java
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 */
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode() { }

    TreeNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you also please provide your TreeNode class?

Comment: yes i have provided the treenode class please review again , i request you to please visit the problem once using the link given by me.

Comment: The answer shows you made a typo. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `for(int k=0;i<left.size();k++)` you need to replace `i` with `k`.